# free elements from array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, size

Probably, this is a very basic question, but here goes anyways. I have an array of size say 10. But, while assigning integers to that array I give only 8 elements. Can I free the memory of 2 elements that are not used ?

Comment: do you have to use arrays ? why not other data structures such as vectors?

Comment: yes. I want to know, if this can be done using arrays

Comment: depends on what you mean by array. The builtin language array is not used much because of this. So we have alternative objects that are more commonly used (like std::vector).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. For dynamic allocation, you can only `free` or `delete` memory that was allocated with `malloc` or `new`. The exact same amount with the exact same pointer. For automatic variables, the memory will be freed automatically.

But since this is C++, use a `std::vector` instead. Please.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you got your array in the first place.

If it is an array that is allocated in the automatic or static storage (i.e. a local or a global) there is nothing you can free, because you did not allocate anything (the compiler did it for you).

If this is a dynamically allocated array, you can achieve the same effect by creating a smaller array with only eight elements, copying the original values into it, and then freeing the original array. This does not guarantee that the amount of memory allocated to your program would necessarily go down, because the allocator of the eight-element array is allowed to allocate space for more elements. If the numbers are 10000 and 8000, on the other hand, you will almost certainly get some savings (although the standard does not guarantee it either).